# How to filter DOM element with only parent and partial content as identifier in PHP

Tags: php, regex, dom, web-scraping

I am able to select the parent div class and all list items, but trying to capture the specific one with UPC number and remove the  tags along with content. Notice no id or class in all children under ".parent" class. This is a screen scrape so no way to add anything. Also, the li order can change, so no counting down.

Looking to capture only...

```
000022200000
```

This is the string/web page...

```
<div class="parent">
   <ul>
       <li>...</li>
       <li><b>UPC:</b>000022200000</li>
```

(these upc#'s are all different obviously and I don't want the other content)

I am using [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to parse the data like so...

```
foreach($shdom2->find('.parent ul li') as $e) {
            $shdom = $shdom.'<p>UPC: '.$e.'</p>';
    }
```

This loop brings me back all list items, now I need to narrow down to the one with UPC#.

I believe I can use a preg_match(), but I have failed at getting one to work for me.

This is a use of preg_match() that did work for a simpler node on the project...

```
if (preg_match('/G00([^\/]*)/i', $e, $regs))
        {
            $r = $regs[0];
            $shdom = $shdom.$r.',';
        }
```

Comment: It's not clear what output you want to get from this. Are you only trying to match <li> with UPC in them? All <li> perhaps?

Comment: @JamesC For now I am playing with "output", but In this case, I am trying to get only the UPC number in my example target. So I want 000022200000 and have to strip out the <b>UPC:</b> and likely the other <li> unless the <b>UPC:</b> can be implemented as part of the selector.

Comment: This would be simpler with PHP's own [DOM](http://php.net/dom) rather than Simple HTML DOM. Is there any special reason why you want/need to use the latter?

Comment: @salathe I was unfamiliar with both when I started the project, but Simple HTML DOM claimed to be more like jQuery selectors so I went that path, because I knew jQuery selectors. Also, the scraping tutorial happened to use this library so made it easy to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the `<b>` tag, grab it's parent, and find your UPC in its children, like this:

```
foreach( $shdom2->find('.parent ul li b') as $b) {
    $li = $b->parent();
    foreach( $li->children() as $child) { 
        echo $child; // This should print your UPC eventually
    }
}
```

You'll have to look at the DOM that is being formed to tell where the UPC is in the children (It will be a text node). You should be able to access it directly with an index, like this, I'm just not sure of the correct index value:

```
foreach( $shdom2->find('.parent ul li b') as $b) {
    if( $b->plaintext === 'UPC:') {
        $li = $b->parent();
        $upc = $li->children( 1); // Change 1 to correct value if wrong
        echo $upc;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I've [created a port](http://viper-7.com/P4ixGv) of the algorithm to PHP's `DOMDocument`:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML( $html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $doc);

foreach( $xpath->query( '//div[@class="parent"]/ul/li/b') as $b) {
    $li = $b->parentNode;
    $upc = $li->childNodes->item(1);
    echo $upc->wholeText;
}
```

You can see that [this outputs](http://viper-7.com/4UOMzX):

```
000022200000
```

Comment: The only problem, I am finding more <b> tags in the same child structure. Is there a way to narrow down the search to <b>UPC: </b>?

Comment: I wouldn't use a regex since that'll be expensive across all `<li><b>` nodes you find. Use an `if` statement in the `foreach`, I'll update my answer.

Comment: children(0) returns <b>UPC:</b>, while 1+ nothing. If I remove children I get <li><b>UPC:</b>000022200000</li>

Comment: I ended up going with yours, but removed the $upc = $li->childNodes->item(1); and added 

$li = str_replace(array('<li><b>UPC:</b>','</li>'),'',$li);

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the regexp:

```
/UPC:\<\/b\>(\d+)/
```

either against each `<li>` if you're traversing the dom or with `preg_match_all()` against the raw document